# error when running command using mpirun in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mpi, openmpi, multiprocess

im trying to run below source code using "mpirun -np 4 test" which 'test' is my file name for below code.
but this kind of error came out

> mpirun noticed that the job aborted but has no info as to the process that caused that situation

my lecturer said it is something from my computer/VM that not allowed multiprocess execution.
I hope someone can tell me the solution. Thank you.

[this is my source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2aij.png)

Comment: could you try naming your binary something other than "test" as "test" is a built-in shell command...

Comment: Or `mpirun -np 4 ./test`

Comment: wowww, thank you its workkk